# POSTing and PUTing a restangular object

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am trying to create a new restangular object, `POST` it, modify it and then `PUT` it.

```
$scope.new_message = Restangular.one('messages');

// This should post
$scope.new_message.save().then(function(message){
    $scope.new_message = message;
});

// This should PUT
$scope.new_message.subject = "Hello world";
$scope.new_message.save()
```

**Unfortunately restangular is sending a PUT request to** `http:/localhost/messages/undefined/5481ebbfe252e4116a8334d0`

**When it should be**
`http://10.211.55.3/messages/5481ebbfe252e4116a8334d0`

It seems that to use `.one()` you must include an `id` as one of the parameters. My question is, how I can leverage the `.save()` functionality without using an `id`

Comment: Well, don't you need some `id` to apply your `PUT` on ?

Comment: @AniketSinha. Yes but the id is fetched from the response of the first put. That part is working fine. The id is `5481ebb...`

Comment: this is known issue. Checkout [https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/944](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/944)  and [https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/892](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/892).